# Disparity between result of numpy gradient applied directly and applied using xarray.apply_ufunc

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray, numpy-ufunc

I'm trying to use xarray's `apply_ufunc` to wrap numpy's `gradient` function, in order to take gradients along one dimension. However, `apply_ufunc` is returning an array with a different shape to the one which using `np.gradient` directly returns:

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

def wrapped_gradient(da, coord):
    """Finds the gradient along a given dimension of a dataarray."""

    dims_of_coord = da.coords[coord].dims
    if len(dims_of_coord) == 1:
        dim = dims_of_coord[0]
    else:
        raise ValueError('Coordinate ' + coord + ' has multiple dimensions: ' + str(dims_of_coord))

    coord_vals = da.coords[coord].values

    return xr.apply_ufunc(np.gradient, da, coord_vals, kwargs={'axis': -1},
                          input_core_dims=[[dim]], output_core_dims=[[dim]],
                          output_dtypes=[da.dtype])



# Test it out by comparing with applying np.gradient directly:
orig = xr.DataArray(np.random.randn(4, 3), coords={'x': [5, 7, 9, 11]}, dims=('x', 'y'))

expected = np.gradient(orig.values, np.array([5, 7, 9, 11]), axis=0)

actual = wrapped_gradient(orig, 'x').values
```

I want expected and actual to be the same, but instead they are different:

```
print(expected.shape)
> (4,3)
print(actual.shape)
> (3,4)
```

(`expected` and `actual` are also not just transposed versions of each other.) I'm confused as to why - my understanding of `apply_ufunc` was that the core dimensions are moved to the end, so that `axis=-1` should always be supplied to the ufunc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xr.apply_ufunc` moves the `input_core_dims` to the last position. 
The dimension that gradient was computed along are moved to the last position, and therefore the resultant shape would be transposed compared with the result by `np.gradient`.

The problem is that in your script the coordinate is not considered in the `apply_ufunc`.
I think you need to pass `input_core_dim`s for all the inputs; in your case, those for `da` and `coord_vals`.
Changing `[[dim]]` to `[[dim], []]` will compute correctly, i.e.,

```
return xr.apply_ufunc(np.gradient, da, coord_vals, kwargs={'axis': -1},
                      input_core_dims=[[dim], []], output_core_dims=[[dim]],
                      output_dtypes=[da.dtype])
```

BTW, I think xarray should raise an Error when input_core_dims does not match those expected for the inputs.
I will raise an issue on Github.

Comment: That fixed it, thank you! (and also writing `expected = np.gradient(orig.values.T, np.array([5, 7, 9, 11]), axis=-1)`).

Comment: However, if I now try to use `dask='parallelized'` (chunking the input as `chunked = orig.chunk({'y': 1})` then I get an error: `ValueError: Chunks do not add up to shape. Got chunks=((1, 1, 1),), shape=(4,)`

Comment: Turns out it actually needs to be `input_core_dims=[[dim], [dim]]`, to account for the fact that `coord_vals` is a 1D array aligned along the same dimension I want to take the gradient along. With this change then `dask='parallelized'` will work.